# Pi Pico won't mount on Ventura

Tags: pi-pico, macos

When I hold down the BOOTSEL button and connect my Pico to my M1 Macbook Air running Ventura, a dialogue box quickly pops up then disappears asking "Allow Accessory to Connect?".  It disappears before I can click OK.

I know that the Pico and Ventura had issues, but is there a workaround for this on MacOS yet?

Comment: Works on my Mac mini M2